# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'IndexBacking' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, cdi, el, propertynotfoundexception

I am trying to develop a JEE application deployed in an EAR.

I have an EJB project and a Dynamic Web project that uses the JSF specification.

Some infos:

- My web application server is Glassfish 5.0.1.
- When I run "java -version" in a terminal, I get:
  "openjdk version" 1.8.0_282 "
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.52.0.23-CA-win64) (build 1.8.0_282-b08)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.52.0.23-CA-win64) (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode) "
- When I run "javac -version", I get:
  "javac 1.8.0_282"
- In eclipse, the installed and selected JRE is
  "Zulu 8.52.0.23"

My @ManagedBean annotated beans are accessible.

But !

My beans marked with "@Named" throw the following exceptions: "javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @ 22,73 action =" # {IndexBacking.doCreateAccount ()} ": Target Unreachable, identifier 'IndexBacking' resolved to null "

Ideas ?

Comment: indexBacking is null.  Did you expect it not to be?

Comment: Actually the author has written `IndexBacking`, capital initial `I`. It should be lower-case, I think.